# How to deploy next.js 9 to AWS Lambda without using Serverless Components

Tags: aws-lambda, next.js, serverless

I would like to simply deploy my Next.js 9 to AWS Lambdas using just API Gateway in front and make a proxy to the static path pointing to S3, but the only available option (without having to write all the stuff from the scratch) is https://github.com/serverless-nextjs/serverless-next.js which is currently using a beta version of Serverless Components (very buggy and lack of control over resources created as it does not uses CloudFormation), also this SLS Component forces the user to use CloudFront which is not my need, I have PR environments created all the time and allocating CloudFront for that is just waste of time/money/resources.

I tried to use the old version of the plugin `serverless-nextjs-plugin` but it seems not to work with Next.js 9, it fails to create the Lambdas for .html generated pages.

Is there any light in the end of this tunnel?

https://github.com/serverless-nextjs/serverless-next.js/issues/296 by this issue it looks like there's no way to do that.

Comment: Hey Marcelo, I sympathize with you and understand what you're saying. I'm on the same boat.. What did you end up doing? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make it work

`serverless.base.yml` file:

```yaml
service: my-app

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  timeout: 10 # seconds
  memorySize: 1792 # Mb

custom:
  webpack:
    packager: yarn
    includeModules:
      forceInclude:
        - chalk

functions:
  nextJsApp:
    handler: server.handler
    events:
      - http: 'ANY /'
      - http: 'ANY {proxy+}'
```

`server.js`:

```js
const { parse } = require('url');
const next = require('next');
const serverless = require('serverless-http');

const app = next({
  dev: false
});

const requestHandler = app.getRequestHandler();

export const handler = serverless(async (req, res) => {
  const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
  await requestHandler(req, res, parsedUrl);
});
```

`wepback.config.js`:

```js
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
  ...

  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: '.next', to: '.next' },
        { from: 'public', to: 'public' }
      ]
    })
  ]
};
```

and here is the trick for working with serverless and webpack, use a `serverless.js` that modifies the `serverless.base.yml` and add all dependencies to the required dependencies to be included in the bundle:

```js
const yaml = require('yaml-boost');
const minimist = require('minimist');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = (() => {
  const params = minimist(process.argv.slice(2));
  const serverless = yaml.load(path.join(__dirname, 'serverless.base.yml'), params);
  const packageJson = require(path.join(__dirname, 'package.json'));

  const dependencies = Object.keys(packageJson.dependencies);
  serverless.custom.webpack.includeModules.forceInclude.push(...dependencies);
  return serverless;
})();
```

Comment: Hey Marcelo,


Can you explain why the webpack config and `serverless.js` dependency injection are necessary? 


For Lambdas I understand that the Next.js app must have a custom server to export its handler wrapped in `serverless-http`, but I don't see where webpack must come in.


I plan to deploy my Next.js SSR/SSG app to an AWS Lambda with API Gateway using AWS SAM as opposed to using `serverless.yml`. This makes me wonder what the webpack dependency injection in `serverless.js` is doing and whether I need to do this within my Next.js app served from a SAM template.

Comment: the reason is the the lambda bundle is made copying the bundled assets from next, but for unknown reasons for me next bundle does not includes the dependencies on it, so I need to force serverless framework to include the dependencies on the lambda bundle so the next runtime can access it.